# При запуске приложения открывается командная строка

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cmd, gui

Имеется файл test.py

При запуске открывается GUI-приложение, всё работает отлично. При помощи pyinstaller собрал его в exe-файл. При запуске test.exe всё продолжает работать верно, но открывается командная строка. Можно ли запускать exe-файл без запуска cmd?

Пробовал запускать pyinstaller с аргументом --noconsole (-w), в этом случае exe-файл вообще не запускается.

Привожу код, может быть, в нём проблема:

```
from speedtest import Speedtest
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        Label(self,
              text="Download:"
              ).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self,
              text="Upload:"
              ).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        Label(self,
              text="Ping:"
              ).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
        Button(self,
               text="Get results",
               command=self.get_results
               ).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)

    def get_results(self):
        st = Speedtest()
        download = '%.3f' % (st.download() / 1048576)
        Label(self,
              text=download + " Mbit/s"
              ).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        upload = '%.3f' % (st.upload() / 1048576)
        Label(self,
              text=upload + " Mbit/s"
              ).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        st.get_servers([])
        ping = '%.3f' % (st.results.ping)
        Label(self,
              text=ping
              ).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
root.title("SpeedTest")
root.geometry("250x150")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо собирать проект с любым ключом из: [-w, --windowed, --noconsole](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options):

```
pyinstaller --noconsole <другие необходимые параметры>
```

Comment: При сборе с ключом -w(,--noconsole,--windowed) получаю следующую ошибку: pyinstaller: error: argument -w/--windowed/--noconsole: ignored explicit argument '(,--noconsole,--windowed)'

Comment: @Liquidвот так надо `pyinstaller --noconsole`

Comment: При использовании ещё одного аргумента ( `pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile <script_name>.py` ) exe-файл не запускается. Ошибка: `failed to execute script test`

Comment: Причём такая ошибка появляется и без аргумента `--onefile`, и при использовании одного лишь `-w`.

Comment: @Liquid такая ошибка бывает, это связано с версией pyinstaller. Попробуйте ее обновить на более новую, или использовать dev-версию https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2137.

`pip uninstall pyinstaller
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

Comment: @Liquid в частности, у меня tkinter собирается с любой комбинацией флагов. Версия pyinstaller 3.6 python 3.8.3

Comment: Я проверил на других проектах с tkinter. Всё работает отлично, проблема явно в этой программе.

Comment: Проблема действительно в программе. Пакет `speedtest` не может работать без консоли. Неясно только, почему не запускается gui. Как исправить эту проблему, не нашёл.