# Убрать консоль при выполнии скрипта

Tags: python, windows, selenium, pyinstaller

Есть питоновский скрипт. Хочу сделать из него исполняемый файл, который будет запускаться с нужными аргументами через ярлык. Проблема в том, что при запуске открывается виндовая консоль, которая при этом не закрывается автоматически после окончания скрипта! Перепробовал различные варианты: переименовал `.py` файл в `.pyw`, собирал с опциями `--noconsole` и `--windowed` -- ничего не помогло. Как убрать эту консоль?

Также используется selenium, так что эта консоль может появляться от драйвера браузера. Как её убрать вообще непонятно.

Comment: Какими средствами вы хотите делать исполняемый файл? Как именно запускаете скрипт (какой командой)?

Comment: @cauf всё вроде указано: pyinstaller, ярлык

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138071/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0

Comment: @cauf пробовал, написано же

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение, может кому-то пригодится. Может показаться безумным, но это единственное что у меня работает.

1. Переименовываем в `.pyw`, судя по докам pyinstaller автоматически поставит нужные опции.
2. РЕДАКТИРУЕМ СОРС selenium-а (лучше делать в venv) `Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py`:

Заменяем создание процесса в методе `start` на это:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False,
                                            creationflags=0x08000000)
```

Ключевое тут `creationflags` с константой типа `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` и `shell=False`. Остальное, вероятно, можно оставить так, как в вашей текущей версии, но я не пробовал.

3. Теперь можно собирать (`--onefile` необязательно, `--noconsole` ставится автоматически из-за расширения файла):

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile script.pyw`

В итоге нет ни консоли от скрипта, ни консоли драйвера!